# Find the entity that is dependent on (or using) a web resource

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to delete a webresource (JS file) that is there in the system.

When I click on delete, it says there are some dependencies and when I click on the  details, it shows this pop up

[image]

This doesn't have the solution in which it is in or the parent entity.

In this case, how do I find the dependent Application ribbon and delete it?

Is there a way to find out the entities that use this web resource?

Answer (score 2):

Application Ribbon can be only one in the system. Add it to a new solution (under Client Extensions) & open the solution in Ribbon workbench. You can find the xml, copy/paste in Notepad++ & search for your webresource name.

This will show the command & you can sort out the button using that command. Then you decide what to do.

Comment: Thanks. Will it be there if we search for it, if the webresource is a JS file?

Comment: I've removed almost everything from the Ribbon customization.xml.  but when I try to delete it still says there is a dependency in Application Ribbon which is  in one of the managed solutions. But one out of 2 Application Ribbon dependency is gone now

Comment: @VigneshSubramanian good. But how come your custom script is added into managed solution dependencies ?

Comment: not really sure, its been there for a long time. I am just seeing it now

Answer (score 2):

The Script Finder in the XrmToolBox can be used in to find the dependencies:

[image]